# How to compare the first element with others in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to get an array where it shows whether each of the element equals to the first element in every row:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,1],[3,3,3],[2,0,1]])
b = a[:,0] == a[:]
print(b)
```

In 1st row should check 1 == 1, 1 == 2, 1 == 1.

In 2nd row should check 3 == 3, 3 == 3, 3 == 3.

In 3rd row should check 2 == 2, 2 == 0, 2 == 1.

However the output it wrong:

```
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False]])
```

Should be:

```
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False]])
```

Now what am I doing wrong and how to get the correct result?

Comment: You might need to reshape your `b` array to make it work via broadcasting, `a[:,0].reshape(-1, 1) == a[:]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To brodcast you need to reshape to add an extra dimension:

```
a[:,0,None] == a
```

Output:

```
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False]])
```